# CSS div problems

Tags: css, html, web, dreamweaver

I seem to be having a problem stacking 3 divs side by side. I've went through a few different pages that gave me codes and tips for how to do this but for some reason it doesn't come out right. Here is the div code I am using in my page, and the info for the divs from the style sheet. Hoping someone can help me out with a fix to what I am doing wrong.

I decided to make another edit because I really didnt give enough info, I have 3 divs side by side but they seem to stick together and one is different, I want them to evenly space to fit flush with the rest of the layout. I have a link to the site so you can see what I have [what I have](http://www.gen2designs.com/index.html)

Also sorry about the mix up with the # missing from the #t2 on the post I accidentally deleted it when making the post its in the code.

```
<div id="testwrap">
    <div id="t1">left</div>
    <div id="t3">right</div>
    <div id="t2">middle</div>
</div>

#testwrap {
width: 933px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

#t1 {
width: 311px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color: #FFF;
height: 220px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
float: left; width:311px;
padding: 10px;
}
 #t2 {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 220px;
width: auto;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: auto;
}
#t3 {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 220px;
width: 311px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
width:311px;
float: right; width:311px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Made a mistake when I was writing the post, its actually #t2 in the coding, changed it in the post and left a link for the page I made to see what it looks like

Comment: They seem to be lined up correctly for me in Chrome, IE9, IE8 and IE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clean working code (Your code is so messy). You can copy paste this to your HTML document. Just change the background color of the divs to your liking.

**http://jsfiddle.net/K3FJe/**

**HTML**

```
<div id="testwrap">
    <div id="t1">left</div>
    <div id="t2">middle</div>
    <div id="t3">right</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#testwrap {
    width: 933px;
    height: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: black;
}

#t1, #t2, #t3 {
    height: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
}

#t1 {
    width: 273px;
    margin: 20px 6px 20px 12px;
    background-color: red;

}

#t2 {
    width: 279px;
    margin: 20px 6px 20px 6px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#t3 {
    width: 273px;
    margin: 20px 12px 20px 6px;
    background-color: green;
}​
```

I updated it with even spaces between them, I think this should work.

Comment: I changed the code with the new values you gave me for the spacing but the last box falls off to the bottom, or I should say the blue box.

Comment: Ok so I added your code and got one part fixed now Im having the exact same problem with the blue box lol heres what it looks like now.http://www.gen2designs.com/index.html

Comment: thanks a bunch IAMTHESTIG you made my night very happy. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Just copy and paste the css code in your style sheet. And in your HTML the middle should be #t2 not #t3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because you're floating t1 and t3, and taking them out of the document flow as a result.  If you float #t2 as well, and change its width to match the resulting space (instead of auto), it should work.

```
#t2 {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 220px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: thanks PRB that actually fixed the problem of them being all on the same level, now I just need to figure out how to space them evenly to go flush with the content box above them

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
#testwrap {
   display: table;
   [...]
}
#t1, #t2, #t3 {
   display : table-cell;
   width: 271px;
}
```

Then remove all the floats.

This way all the column will always have the same height.